# How to access file inside JAR file as a string

Tags: java

I packaged some classes and libraries into a single JAR file. But the current code cannot access the files inside the JAR file as it is.

```
String scenarioFile = "netlogo/Altruism.nlogo";
// InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(scenarioFile);
simulator = HeadlessWorkspace.newInstance();
simulator.open(scenarioFile);
```

the .open expects a string but i read that i need to use inputstream format thus its not working. Is there any other workaround?

Comment: What is `HeadlessWorkspace.`?

Comment: @Tunaki hey Tunaki, its a package "import org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace;"

Comment: I see there a [`openFromSource`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/4.1/docs/javadoc/org/nlogo/headless/HeadlessWorkspace.html#openFromSource(java.lang.String)) taking the String. Maybe you can read the InputStream in a String and pass it to that method? Otherwise, you need to copy the resource inside a temp file and use that path...

Comment: @Tunaki thank you for the comment, it helped loads!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Tunaki i was able to get a way about doing it and it worked!

what i did was download commons.io.jar file

```
import org.apache.commons.io.*;
```

and then use an inputstream to read the file and then convert it to a string and use openFromSource method that Tunaki suggested of HeadlessWorkspace package to read it.

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(NetlogoFile);
            String scenarioFile = IOUtils.toString(is, "UTF-8");
      simulator = HeadlessWorkspace.newInstance();
      simulator.openFromSource(scenarioFile);
```